# How do I deploy an outlook add-in created with Yo Office to our own ubuntu server?

Tags: office-addins

After putting the app on the online webserver React is no longer recognized. Locally everything works fine.

Just to be sure it was not my fault I started from scratch again by doing the following steps.

**Step 1 - Create the app:**
mkdir reacttest
cd reacttest
yo office
select Office Add-in project using React framework
name it ReactTest
select outlook as the office client
let it do it's work
cd ReactTest
npm audit fix
adjust the manifest by filling in the SupportUrl DefaultValue

**Step 2 - test the app**
npm start
sideload add-in by loading the manifest into Outlook
click the button
If all is well you should see the Welcome screen.

**Step 3 - Build**
npm run build

**Step 4 - Upload and test**
upload the content of the dist folder to a place on the online webserver
replace the https://localhost:3000 in the manifest by the location on the webserver
sideload add-in by loading the renewed manifest into Outlook
click the button
nothing shows in the sidepanel

**Step 5 - Check in outlook debugger**
rightclick the sidepanel and show the element inspector
check the console for the error
it shows 3 errors **the biggest of which seems to be that React is not known and cause the add-in not work**?

```
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: React
    react (vendor.297c97ec99bb1c2af14d.js:16:1502)
    o (vendor.297c97ec99bb1c2af14d.js:1:159)
    (anonieme functie) (vendor.297c97ec99bb1c2af14d.js:16:1336)
    o (vendor.297c97ec99bb1c2af14d.js:1:159)
    (anonieme functie) (vendor.297c97ec99bb1c2af14d.js:1:949)
    Globale code (vendor.297c97ec99bb1c2af14d.js:1:957)

[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: React
    react (app.297c97ec99bb1c2af14d.js:23:8683)
    o (app.297c97ec99bb1c2af14d.js:1:159)
    ./index.tsx (app.297c97ec99bb1c2af14d.js:23:7746)
    o (app.297c97ec99bb1c2af14d.js:1:159)
    (anonieme functie) (app.297c97ec99bb1c2af14d.js:23:8631)
    o (app.297c97ec99bb1c2af14d.js:1:159)
    (anonieme functie) (app.297c97ec99bb1c2af14d.js:1:949)
    Globale code (app.297c97ec99bb1c2af14d.js:1:957)

[Error] Error: Office.js has not fully loaded. Your app must call "Office.onReady()" as part of it's loading sequence (or set the "Office.initialize" function). If your app has this functionality, try reloading this page.
    (anonieme functie) (office.debug.js:1643:263)
    validateFunction (office.debug.js:287)
```

These are the dependencies in package.json (used in production if I understand correctly)

```
"dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/office-js-helpers": "^1.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.6.1",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "^6.138.1",
    "react": "^16.8.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.1"
},
```

react and react-dom are clearly present

I expect the app to run on our webserver and that react is available and works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the webpack configuration for the production build marks React and ReactDOM as external. You can either load them explicitly with script links in the HTML page, or go to /config/webpack.prod.js and remove the externals section:

```
  externals: {
        'react': 'React',
        'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
    },
```

Doing the latter will cause webpack to load React into the bundle.

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much.